# Sample Space & Combinations/Permutations

Tags: probability, statistics

This is the question:  "List the sample space for three individuals chosen at random to vote either Democrat or Republican.  List the distinct combinations and permutations."

These are what I got for my answers but I don't think my sample space is correct since it's asking for sample space for three individuals chosen, could some of you smart fellows help me out please?

Sample Space: {D,R}

Permutations: {D,D,D}, {R,R,R}, {D,R,D}, {D,D,R}, {R,D,D}, {R,R,D}, {D,R,R}, {R,D,R}

Combinations: {D,D,D}, {D,D,R}, {D,R,R}, {R,R,R}

What did I do wrong?  I feel something is amiss.

Comment: The permutations should be listed as ordered triples rather than sets.

Comment: "Bumped by Community user" - stop *bumping* community user

Answer (score 0):

Sample space is set of all possible outcomes of an experiment. Your sample space would have been right if the experiment have performed only on one person. For three people under experiment each have possibility to say D or R so your sample space will be having  2x2x2=8 possible outcomes. In that way Permutations is sample space. But if you just wanted to count the vote in possible outcome then combination will be the sample space. (0 votes to R in first possible outcome, 1 in second and so on..) Hope this explains your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set of tuples ${(p_1,p_2,p_3)} $ where $p_i$ can be the vote of the $ith$ person. Thus $(D,D,R)$ corresponds to the outcome that the first person votes Democratic, the second votes Democratic and the third votes Republican